# Question about the history of dyadic models in harmonic analysis

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, harmonic-analysis

Who first used the expression "dyadic model" in the sense of [this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/07/27/dyadic-models/) by Terence Tao?

Say you are a harmonic analyst trying to prove a result, e.g., something like the Carleson-Hunt Theorem, but it's just too hard. So you consider instead a simplified dyadic model, for instance using Walsh series, you work out this simpler situation and then you adapt your argument to the real McCoy.

**Q1:** What is the history of this methodology in harmonic analysis?

Another related but different question: what about, more generally, the history of dyadic analysis?

**Q2:** What were some of the main steps in the historical development of this subject?

Note that I mostly care about Q1. As for Q2 it is probably too broad as stated since this could be interpreted as asking about the history of related fields like: renormalization group analysis, multiscale analysis etc. In order to make this more focused I would like to restrict to techniques based on dyadic cubes in harmonic analysis as in these two surveys: https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05639 and http://www.math.unm.edu/~crisp/papers/lectures.pdf

Comment: The last link is dead, but the text can be found [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507021812/http://www.math.unm.edu/~crisp/papers/lectures.pdf).